# Callable in Always Null

Tags: java, unit-testing, callable

I have the following Java code used to retry a certain action

```
package helpers;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public final class Retry {

    public static <V> V execute(Callable<V> action, Duration retryInterval, int retryCount)
        throws AggregateException {

        List<Throwable> exceptions = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int retry = 0; retry < retryCount; ++retry) {

            try {
                if (retry > 0)
                    Thread.sleep(retryInterval.toMillis());
                return action.call();

            } catch (Throwable t) {
                exceptions.add(t);
            }
        }
        throw new AggregateException(exceptions);
    }

    public static <V> Future executeAsync(Callable<V> action, Duration retryInterval, int retryCount)
        throws AggregateException {

        FutureTask<V> task = new FutureTask<>(action);
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        return executor.submit(task);
    }
}
```

I am am attempting to test the functionality of the synchronous code via

```
package helpers;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.text.MessageFormat;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class RetryTest {

    private Integer counter = 0;
    private Callable<Integer> calculator;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        calculator = () -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
                counter++;
                System.out.println(MessageFormat.format(
                    "Counter = {0}", Integer.toString(counter)));
            }
            if (counter < 6)
                throw new Exception();
            return counter;
        };
    }

    @Test
    public void execute() throws AggregateException {

        Integer result = Retry.execute(calculator, Duration.ofSeconds(1), 3);
        assertEquals(9, java.util.Optional.ofNullable(result));
    }
}
```

But `calculator` is null in `Retry.execute(calculator, Duration.ofSeconds(1), 3);`, why and what am I doing wrong here?

I am using Junit 4.12.

---

I have also tried the full syntax

```
@Before
    public void init() {
        calculator = new Callable<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public Integer call() throws Exception {
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
                    counter++;
                    System.out.println(MessageFormat.format(
                        "Counter = {0}", Integer.toString(counter)));
                }
                if (counter < 6)
                    throw new Exception();
                return counter;
            }
        };
    }
```

still null.

Comment: I wouldn't think this would effect it, but the docs say that the method being `@Test`ed needs to be public.

Comment: I have added `public` and edited the question to reflect that. Still `calculator` is null?

Comment: Well, if `init` simply isn't being called, it doesn't matter which form the calculator function is in. Have you verified if that method is being called at all?

Comment: Just established that this is _not_ being called - but have you any idea why? Thanks for your time.

Comment: I tried but it works i think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I tested using `JUnit 3` and `@Before` is never called. Then I tested with JUnit 4 and `@Before` is being called , try to see your JUnit Versions.

Comment: Just what I was about to suggest. That's the only thing I can find while searching. JUnit being outdated. `@Before` was introduced in 4.

Comment: can he write @Before tag without using Junit4 or latest version.He will get compile error if he use.

Comment: @drowny Not Always. I have my Env for running JUnit3 and JUnit4 and call functions of JUnit4 to JUnit3. Yeah It is  mess but it can compile. MAybe he need to check his dependencies.

Comment: Was using three different test libraries!!

Answer (score 1):

Can you check with this test code ?

```
public class RetryTest {


    @Test
    public void execute() throws AggregateException {

        Integer result = Retry.execute(getCallableCalculater(), Duration.ofSeconds(1), 3);
        assertEquals(9, java.util.Optional.ofNullable(result));
    }

    private Callable<Integer> getCallableCalculater() {

        final Integer[] counter = {0};
        return () -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
                counter[0]++;
                System.out.println(MessageFormat.format(
                        "Counter = {0}", Integer.toString(counter[0])));
            }
            if (counter[0] < 6)
                throw new Exception();
            return counter[0];
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: This will clearly work. I want to use @Before though, thanks!!

Comment: I will edit the question and provide these, thanks for your time.

Comment: Can u debug with adding to inside of init method. is it calling ? Because when i running your code ,everthing is ok.

Comment: I've got it, I have three different test libraries installed in the project!! I am new to Java - sorry for the wasted time! You've been a great help - thanks very much.

Comment: No problem mate